How to propagate Spring Security Context into WebClient
I am using Spring MVC to create a service and Spring WebFlux to use WebClient. How can I propagate SecurityContext inside WebClient to access the login user that was set with SecurityContextHolder?

I have found two ways to do this, but they don't seem right to me.

ReactiveSecurityContextHolder + contextWrite

Everywhere where WebClient is used, you must add contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication)) before the block call. E.g.,
pingClient.ping()
    .flatMap(v -> pingClient.ping())
    .flatMap(v -> pingClient.ping())
    .contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication))
    .block();

To retrieve the login user:
public static Mono<User> getReactiveUser() {
  return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
      .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
      .map(Authentication::getPrincipal)
      .cast(User.class);
}


SecurityReactorContextConfiguration

SecurityReactorContextConfiguration adds a login user to the reactive context. The configuration class is package-private, and it will be included if your application depends on one of the following libraries: spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client or spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server (source). If you do not use any of the listed libraries, you have to add the configuration class manually:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(SecurityConfig.ReactiveSecurity.class)
public class SecurityConfig {

  static final class ReactiveSecurity implements ImportSelector {

    @Override
    public String[] selectImports(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata) {
      return new String[]{
          "org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.SecurityReactorContextConfiguration"
      };
    }
  }
}

With this, the login user is stored inside the reactive context under the org.springframework.security.SECURITY_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTES key. An example of how to retrieve the login user from the context base on ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction:
public class SecurityUtils {

  static final String SECURITY_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTES = "org.springframework.security.SECURITY_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTES";

  private SecurityUtils() {
  }

  public static Mono<User> getReactiveUser() {
    return Mono.deferContextual(Mono::just)
        .cast(Context.class)
        .flatMap(SecurityUtils::getAuthentication)
        .map(Authentication::getPrincipal)
        .filter(User.class::isInstance)
        .cast(User.class);
  }

  private static Mono<Authentication> getAuthentication(Context ctx) {
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(getAttribute(ctx, Authentication.class));
  }

  private static <T> T getAttribute(Context ctx, Class<T> clazz) {
    // NOTE: SecurityReactorContextConfiguration.SecurityReactorContextSubscriber adds this key
    if (!ctx.hasKey(SECURITY_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTES)) {
      return null;
    }
    Map<Class<T>, T> attributes = ctx.get(SECURITY_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTES);

    return attributes.get(clazz);
  }
}


My configuration
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

Application properties
spring.reactor.context-propagation=auto

Setting user in SecurityContextHolder
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
User user = new User("User", "", true, true, true, true, List.of());
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "", List.of());
context.setAuthentication(authentication);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);

Creating WebClient, where I would like to set Authorization header taken from login User class.
public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
  WebClient webClient = webClientBuilder
      .filter(securityExchangeFilter)  // setting Authorization header
      .build();
}

